# Using map theme on qfield?

Tags: qgis, layers, style, thematic-map, qfield

I created two presets on qgis and they work very well when switching from one to another, yet on qfield and when I choose a map theme some layers are not displayed especially those that have a ruled style.

I'm blocked at this step.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I wonder if your problem is related to the problem I've encountered and described here?: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265820/how-to-get-xyz-tiles-to-work-in-qfield

Answer (score 1):

There is a good resource you check out that may fix your issue here: [Configure Map Themes¶](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/map-themes.html)

[image]

Comment: I did this before I ask the question and didn't work for me.