# How to get XYZ tiles to work in QField?

Tags: qgis, qfield, xyz-tiles

There seems to be a newly formed issue in displaying (?) XYZ tiles in QField.

In preparing a project in QGIS (desktop) I have for perhaps the last year successfully viewed XYZ tiles in QField after having added tiles in to a QGIS project via the directions outlined in the answer of @MatthiasKuhn (~3rd answer from the top) to this post: [Adding Basemaps from Google or Bing in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20191/adding-basemaps-from-google-or-bing-in-qgis/217670#217670)

(See also: https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2016/10/26/qgis-xyz-tile-wmts-preview/)

However, recently the XYZ tile layers, while working fine on the desktop, do not either display or copy over in or into QField. (they do seem to be listed in the QField application's legend, though they are "greyed out")

I have usually used the QConsolidate plugin to transfer my project, but have now tested with the QFieldSync plugin also.

If the methods described in the linked answer above are no longer a successful way to access XYZ tiles (such as google satellite) in QField, **what is a current way to access XYZ tiles in a QField project?**

[could the web addresses for the tiles just have changed?]

Using QField 10.4 - Kesch on Android 5.1.1 from a project prepared on QGIS 2.18.15 (Win 7).

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen the "greyed out" layers in the QField, however it may have been a bug because I can usually make it go away. If the title of the layer is grey you may need to make the layer visible by pressing the layer and holding it for a few seconds, then selecting the option to make it visible.

I was able to get the Bing and OSM maps to work however I can't get the google maps to work. There may be an issue with Google Maps and QField.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now [Jan 2019] resolved (at least for me) using QGIS 3.4 and the current version of QFIELD (~1.0.rc1).

Thank you so much QFIELD developers!

See also:
https://new.opengis.ch/2019/01/08/qfield-1-0-rc1/

Comment: We've been using. Beta version of Geo data Explorer and found the workflow and efficiency and blessings great Please check out Tech Maven Geospatial's amazing new GIS app about to be released to all the app stores http://GeoDataEXPLORER.world  . Offline vector tile base Maps and overlays,raster tiles  (mbtiles and gpkg) and local GIS vector files from Shape files, filegeodatabase, geojson, KML,gpx, csv and geopackage
Online services connect to ESRI dynamic map services and OGC WMS and TILES from WMTS and XYZ/TMS TILE servers , build in base map picker and online weather. Swipe to compare a